# Binding to a Non Dependency Object in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

I have a statement in xaml as below :

```
<my:CMIconText Icon="Attachment" Text="Logo" />
```

where CMIconText is a class coming from a abc.Core.dll and Text is a string property in that class.

I want to bind Text using Staticbinding but as "Text" is not a dependency property I am unable to do so. The issue is that i cannot made it as a dependency property as the abc.Core.dll is being used by multiple other projects.

Is there other alternative that without changing in dll I can bind the property?

Thanks,

Abdi

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Attached Dependency Property on your object to watch the binding and pass the value statically to you CMIconText object. This works better with a OneWay binding, but it could be done for a two-way binding.

```
public class TextBoxExtension
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AttachedTextProperty;

    static TextBoxExtension()
    {
        AttachedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AttachedText", typeof (string), typeof (TextBoxExtension), new PropertyMetadata(default(string), TextAttachedChanged));
    }

    public static string GetAttachedText(TextBox sender)
    {
        return (string) sender.GetValue(AttachedTextProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAttachedText(TextBox sender, string value)
    {
        sender.SetValue(AttachedTextProperty, value);
    }

    private static void TextAttachedChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TextBox) sender).Text = e.NewValue as string;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do that in the XAML :

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" controls:TextBoxExtension.AttachedText="{Binding Name}" />
```

This is way simpler than reimplementing the whole class. Of course, you need to change the references of `TextBox` to your own object. But because I didn't have it, it was the closest I could give you an example with.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a separate class similar properties and behavior, but with dependency properties where needed. You might wish to have it extend `CMIconText` (especially if you can override the `Text` property to provide the new implementation; even if it doesn't make sense to change the base property to a DP, maybe you can just modify it to be `virtual`). I'd avoid extending the class if can't have the base `Text` be `virtual`. In that case, I'd make the class completely separate, with appropriate methods (or [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)) to convert from/to `CMIconText`.

```
public class SilverlightCMIconText : CMIconText
{
    public override string Text
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
}
<local:SilverlightCMIconText Icon="Attachment" Text="{StaticResource Whatev}" />
```